# LuaAlchemy callglobal

Tags: actionscript-3, lua, alchemy

I'm using LuaAlchemy with AS3 and am currently trying to call global function in lua script. Running whole script file works perfectly, but when I try to call callGlobal(), I get Lua error: attempt to call a nil value.

function call:

```
lua_interpreter.callGlobal("func",3)
```

lua script:

```
function func(a)
 return a
end
```

Comment: Please show how do you load Lua script. Make sure that it is actually loaded (put an `error("loaded")` somewhere, for example and see if it crashes).

Answer (score 0):

I Solved the same problem this way:

```
[Embed(source="../lua/test.lua", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
static var _testLuaClass:Class;


static var lua_interpreter:LuaAlchemy = new LuaAlchemy(LuaAssets.filesystemRoot());
static var luaTestAsset:ByteArrayAsset = ByteArrayAsset(new _testLuaClass());

lua_interpreter.doString(luaTestAsset.toString());

trace(lua_interpreter.callGlobal("func",3));
```

and the Lua script file is the same as yours.